# problem with passing a string in onSubmit in createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

im new in Redux. I do a application Rest Countries Api, and i need from api all countries, and all region onChange in my submit with option.
My idea was pass to args in dispatch in component url:string, but i have all time problem and console write me "index.js:1 A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload`. Value: async (dispatch, getState) => {
return await fetch(url).then(res => res.json());"
I try solve this problem with use middleware, but still don't work :(
my code in sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-cerf-8sbh0?file=/src/redux/store.js

Thanks all for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There looks to be two issues, you are creating the async thunk with name `countries/getUsers` instead of `countries/getCountries`. Also you have `getCountries` as a function that returns a function so it's not really executing how you expect. Try the following:

```
export const getCountries = createAsyncThunk(
  "countries/getCountries",
  async (url) => {
    return await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
  }
);
```

If you do need `dispatch` or similar, you can use a [second argument](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) which is `thunkApi`:

```
export const getCountries = createAsyncThunk(
  "countries/getCountries",
  async (url, thunkAPI) => {
    const { dispatch } = thunkAPI;
    return await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
  }
);
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-aryabhata-pzxbj?file=/src/redux/countresSlice.js).

Comment: All working, Thank You !!

Comment: Sounds great, mark the answer if it did help resolve the issue